# Django can't find my DetailView with Primary Key

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to make a simple page with Django where posts are being displayed using primary keys. However, the DetailView page with my posts can't be displayed.

This is my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
posted_date = timezone.now()
text = models.TextField()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("postdetail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

and here is my url pattern list:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name="postdetail"), 
url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"), 
url(r'^thanks/$', views.Thanks.as_view(), name="thanks"), 
url(r'^postlist/$', views.PostList.as_view(), name="postlist"), 
]
```

The template is in my templates folder under the name "post_detail.html".

Here is the DetailView:

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
context_object_name = 'post_details'
model = Post
```

I can't see where I might have a mistake. I have a ListView that shows my posts including the primary keys. But when I try to open the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/1/`
I get:

```
`Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/1/
Using the URLconf defined in myproj.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='postdetail']
^$ [name='index']
^thanks/$ [name='thanks']
^postlist/$ [name='postlist']
The current path, posts/1/, didn’t match any of these.
```

Do you have a clue why the URL cannot be found? Thank you very much.`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [url()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#url) use [path()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#path)

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = "index"),
    path('posts/<int:pk>', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name = "postdetail"),
    path('postlist/', views.PostList.as_view(), name="postlist"),
    path('thanks', views.Thanks.as_view(), name = "thanks"),
]
```

NB: [url()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#url) been deprecated since version 3.1 and removed in 4.0

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm using Django3. Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: got any errors? what is the problem you facing now?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access : http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/1/ when you define the following http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/1 without the backlash.

Try : http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/1

Comment: Hi Gaëtan GR, thanks for the suggestion. However, my browser automatically adds the "/" at the end, even if I don't include it.

Comment: Because usually it excepts the "/"  which is a bit of a convention, edit your path with the "/"  at the end of your path, like that : r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)$/'

Comment: *  r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/$' or maybe even r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/?$' because this should accept both

Answer (score 0):

First Things Is Your Views. You can send your database data with return it to the HTML.

**views.py**

```
def post(request,id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'blog/index.html',{'post':post})
```

and before sending data into the HTML you should get the post id in your urls.py

**urls.py**

```
    path('post/<int:id>', views.post, name='post.blog')
```

then in your HTML you can handle that data comes from your views.py

index.html

```
<div class="post-content content">{{ post.body|safe }}</div>
```

Comment: Did you read the question properly ? The problem is syntax related why are you talking about database ? Also he's using class based views not function based views and finally he cannot use the path method ...

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks I tried your suggestion, but I get the same error.

Comment: @tobbog- whats your problem